# Probability of a ball exploding exactly $N$ times during its upward flight

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

I throw a ball vertically up into the air. Starting at time $t=0$, for each moment of time it is in the air (i.e. at each point on the real line) it has a probability that it will explode given by $f(t)\textrm{dt}$. It flies for time $T$ and permanently halts at the top of its arc.

Once it has exploded it immediately rebuilds and continues its flight as if nothing has happened, such that it could potentially explode multiple times during its flight.

If I know the probability that it will explode at least once, and the probability it will explode at least twice (etc, such that I know the probability that it will explode at least $N$ times), how do I calculate the probability that the ball will explode exactly $N$ times?

I imagine for the problem "what's the probability it happens exactly once", one has 
$$P\left(explodes\ exactly\ once\right)=\left(\int_{0}^{T}f(t)\textrm{dt}\right)\left(1-\left(\int_{0}^{T}f(t)\textrm{dt}\right)^2\right)$$

such that it happens "at least once" *and* "not twice or more". Am I right?

How are these "exactly N times" problems related to the Poisson distribution, given the variable success $P\left(success\right)=f(t)\textrm{dt}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, the probability the ball explodes exactly $N$ times is

$$
Pr(explodes\ at\ least\ N\ times)-Pr(explodes\ at\ least\ N+1\ times)
$$

since contained within the space of events where the ball explodes *at least* $N$ times are all the times where the ball explodes *at least* $N+1$ times.

Note this is

$$\left(\int_{0}^{T}f(t)dt\right)^N-\left(\int_{0}^{T}f(t)dt\right)^{N+1}$$

or

$$\left(\int_{0}^{T}f(t)dt\right)^N\left(1-\int_{0}^{T}f(t)dt\right)
$$

which is the probability it explodes at least $N$ times *and* doesn't explode again.